# Use Catel ServiceLocator in constructor of control

Tags: c#, catel

I have GridControl and want to use the ServiceLocator.Default instance to retrieve objects (e.g. IMessageService) in the contructor of the control. No problem at run-time but the control throws an exception at design time - the control does not shows up in the Visual Studio designer.

A not-null check on ServiceLocator.Default does not help. How can I use the service locator in the ctor of the control with full designer support?

```
public MyGridControl()
    {
        if (ServiceLocator.Default != null)
        {
            this.mySettingService = ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveType<IRosySettingService>();
            if (this.mySettingService != null)
            {
                var mediator = ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveType<IMessageMediator>();
                mediator.Register<String>(this, SaveSettings, MessageKeys.SaveGridSettings);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prevent code from running in the designer. You can do it as follows:

```
public MyGridControl()
{
    if (CatelEnvironment.IsInDesignMode)
    {
        return;
    }

    // TODO: Use service locator and all runtime code
}
```